# Strange things happening for me with Bootstrap's 992px breakpoint

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, breakpoints

Can anyone help me understand, when ONLY at 992px, the viewpoint width becomes strange. It seems to jump to the 768px breakpoint when at 992px or below.

Snippet here:
http://www.codeply.com/go/beilYT04YA

EDIT:
Why is this getting so many  downvotes?

I've asked all my mentors about this and they haven't the slightest as to why it's happening.

Was hoping someone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Actually this is a good question - just your code is overly complex for a simple question.)*

Your CSS uses a lot of declarations like this one:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  header .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    ...
```

This implies a break-point at anything up to, and including, 992.

```
[  --> max  ]
```

Bootstrap has it's breakpoints like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, ...
```

This implies a breakpoint from, and including, 992 and up.

```
[  min --->  ]
```

So what you have here is a sweet spot at 992 where both conditions are true.

To fix this, just -1 on the max ... i.e. `@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {`

Comment: I see! Next I make a question, I'll be sure to just minimize and simplify the code.

Comment: You also mentioned bootstrap has its breakpoints using min-width. Is using min-width instead of max-width the standard/more popular?

Comment: And thank you a bunch for explaining it for me! Many thanks!

Comment: re: min-width vs. max-width ... it all depends.  Both make sense.  TWBS uses the mobile first approach... so it's default is (xs) size.  Then min-width--and--up the next, then the next... so as it increments it changes the behavior.  For me, I choose the method that means less work, quicker edits.